# Wait time for Google Cloud service account role change to propagate

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-iam

I am using a downloaded JSON file containing service account keys, instead of ADC, with code running on my local developer machine and communicating with live GCP Firestore.

After adding a service account to a role, in my case `roles/datastore.user`, do I have to do anything before it takes effect?

E.g. wait 15 minutes, redownload the JSON, restart some services, something else?

Question relates to this error in automated tests running on my machine.

```
Test method MyProject.Data.Repositories.FirestoreRepositoryTests.FirestoreAccountDocRepository_UpdateAsync__updates threw exception: 
Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="PermissionDenied", Detail="Permission denied on resource project my-project-prodlike.", DebugException="Grpc.Core.Internal.CoreErrorDetailException: {"created":"@1642697226.430711000","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:172.217.169.74:443","file":"/Users/einari/Projects/grpc/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1074,"grpc_message":"Permission denied on resource project my-project-prodlike.","grpc_status":7}")
```

**Note** - I'm using **Contrib.Grpc.Core.M1** since I'm on new MacBook.

**Note** - I'm no longer using the above and now using Google's workaround GRPC lib adapter, just in case. See https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/7560#issuecomment-975414370.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The permission denied problem was being caused by an incorrect project name (and not permission actually being denied).

At the top of the Google Cloud Console is the name of the current project. However, that's actually just a pointless alias, the real project identifier is not displayed by default, though it is in the URL in the browser.

Of course, the error message implies it found its target resource and it denied access.

I'm so tired.